# Constraint Layout textview width set to 0dp is not showing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I'm using an android intro book to set up a Constraint Layout which i think I've done correctly. The preview looks perfect, but when I run it the textviews don't show up, only the image view.

If I change the textviews' widths to "wrap_content" they show up but the format is wrong. This leads me to believe the problem is that the width is to "0dp". I don't understand why this is happening, my xml is identical to the books'. Any feedback for a beginner would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/crime_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Crime Title"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/crime_date"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Crime Date"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/crime_title"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_solved"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: did you solve this issue? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: Tbh i can't completely remember but i think i was missing a dependency or maybe a problem with gradle. Try researching requirements to use constraint layout, hopefully that will help.